# Find language culture vbscript and Advanced Installer

Tags: c#, vbscript, advanced-installer

I am using `advanced installer`, and during the installation i will  collect data while the users will be installing the product.
I need to see which `culture` they have on their `local machine`. (Not the OS language) .

> From Control Panel > Region > Location Tab (this location language). -
>   Windows 8.1 OS

From advanced installer  , i am calling a custom action which will call the `vbscript function` that will get the `culture language` and save it in a property.
Now i am using the function `GetLocale()` which if i will run it a script will return the correct `LanguageId`.
Although if i put the code inside the `function` and call it from `advanced installer` will ALWAYS return the `languageID = 1033` which is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the property [UserLanguageID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372384(v=vs.85).aspx). You can read the value of a Windows Installer property like this:

```
val = Session.Property("UserLanguageID")
```

**Very important!** You can get/set property values only in immediate custom actions, not deferred ones.

Now, if we go talking about [how good it is to use VBScript custom actions or not](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robmen/archive/2004/05/20/136530.aspx), this is another long and old story.

Comment: don't forget to mark the answer as correct, so it will help others too